# Text Field issue with 4.2 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

My app works as supposed on an iPhone running iOS 4.1 but not on iOS 4.2. I have an UITextField set to first responder but the keyboard does not show up.

I CANT NOT make UitextField userInteractionEnabled = TRUE. Text field should be non editable.

Is there any way I can do it

Comment: Do you want a read-only text field to become first responder? And what is UIInputField? Do you mean UITextField?

Comment: Yes I have PIN control the same we have in iPhone (Pass code lock). User can tap on number on keypad but dont select the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by disabling UIView user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the UITextField editable.. and change it to Non-Editable soon as user touches it... and then display the number keypad to enter code..